# How to add last item empty into a list of dynamic array

Tags: android

I have a dynamic array of list into which i want to add last item as " " (empty). Something like this :

```
list.add("Test");
list.add("Working");
list.add("");
```

I tried below code, but that doesn't seem to work, any idea

```
for (int k = 0; k <arraysize; k++) {

                    list.add(getlist().get(k));
                    if(k == -1){
                        list.add("");
                    }

}
```

Comment: k starts on 0, so, If you increment k in the loop, k will never have the value -1. You need to compare k == arraysize to insert the empty value.

Comment: Thanks Victor. Got that

Comment: actually you have to accept the more efficient anwser, but whatever

Comment: No worries my friend @gmetax. Voting for you as well. Cheers

Comment: It's not about the rp, but when someone check this question he will see as first not the "best" answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int k = 0; k <arraysize; k++) {

                    list.add(getlist().get(k));
                    if(k == arraysize-1){
                        list.add("");
                    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

do something like that.

```
List<String> getList = getlist();
for (String item : getList) {
    list.add(item);
}
getList.add("");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int k = 0; k <arraysize; k++) {

                    list.add(getlist().get(k));
                    if(k == array.size()-1){
                        list.add("");
                    }

}
```

Try this

Comment: If you have any problem ask me i will give u better answer

Comment: Thanks @akhil. Cheers

Comment: Mark as true. So its helpful for others